# How do I loop over an array of objects to return a property dependent on a corresponding property within that object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I created a function here that takes in an array (items) and a string as parameters. I need to loop over the items array of objects and find the itemName property that matches the string argument that will be passed into the function. Once that is found I need to return the price property of that same object where the matching string was found. Hopefully I explained the objective efficiently.

I'm pretty sure i'm about 90% where I need to be here, but my loop doesn't seem to work beyond the first index item. Not sure what i'm missing.

```
 let items = [
  {
    itemName: "Bad Habits",
    type: "book",
    price: 13.99
  },
  {
    itemName: "Acer 5000",
    type: "computer",
    price: 299.99
  },
  {
    itemName: "Center of Gravity",
    type: "book",
    price: 15.00
  }
]

function priceLookup(items, string){
  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  if (string == items[i].itemName) {
    return items[i].price;
  } else {
    return "No item found with that name";
  }
}
}
```

Comment: Well, if the first item doesn't match, the `return "No item found"` block runs. You need to do that after all of the items have been checked.

Comment: basically, you can only safely say that you haven't found an item with the given name once you have checked _all_ items in your array (that is if you're doing a linear-search, which you are). So you can't have the logic of  "No item found with that name" inside your for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

return statement "No item found" is triggered when if statement is false (interrupt iteration). Try with return statement outside the for loop, this works.

```js
function priceLookup(items, string){
  for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (items[i].itemName == string) {
      return items[i].price;
    }  
  }
  return "No item found with that name";
}
console.log(priceLookup(items, "Center of Gravity"));
```